# Object inside of an array

Tags: kotlin

What I want to do is to add an object in array something like code below, but my Ide returns some errors, I don't understand what the problem is

```kotlin
val sachmelebi = [
    {
      name: 'ხინკალი',
      link: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=%E1%83%AE%E1%83%98%E1%83%9C%E1%83%99%E1%83%90%E1%83%9A%E1%83%98&oq=%E1%83%AE%E1%83%98%E1%83%9C%E1%83%99%E1%83%90%E1%83%9A%E1%83%98&aqs=chrome..69i57j46j0l6.1143j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'
    },
    {
      name: 'მწვადი',
      link: 'https://www.google.com/search?q=%E1%83%9B%E1%83%AC%E1%83%95%E1%83%90%E1%83%93%E1%83%98&oq=%E1%83%9B%E1%83%AC%E1%83%95%E1%83%90%E1%83%93%E1%83%98&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l7.983j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8'
    },
    {
      name: 'მაკარონის წასახემსებელი',
      link: 'https://gemrielia.ge/recipe/6594-xraSuna-makaronis-wasaxemsebeli-romelic-wuTebSi-mzaddeba/'
    }
```

Comment: The errors will tell you what the problem is. This doesn't look like valid kotlin syntax (from what I remember anyway). Please share the errors

Comment: I'm guessing that your problem is that this is not Kotlin syntax. The [basic syntax overview](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html) might be of help to you.

Comment: You probably want to create a data class for something that has a `name` and `link`, then make an `arrayOf(those, objects)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet provided in the question is not valid Kotlin syntax. I would suggest to create a `data class` for your entries and then store them in a list. Below you can find an example:

```kotlin
data class Entry( // use a better name than "Entry"
    val name: String,
    val link: String
)

val sachmelebi = listOf(
    Entry(
        "ხინკალი",
        "https://www.google.com/search?q=%E1%83%AE%E1%83%98%E1%83%9C%E1%83%99%E1%83%90%E1%83%9A%E1%83%98&oq=%E1%83%AE%E1%83%98%E1%83%9C%E1%83%99%E1%83%90%E1%83%9A%E1%83%98&aqs=chrome..69i57j46j0l6.1143j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
    ),
    Entry(
        "მწვადი",
        "https://www.google.com/search?q=%E1%83%9B%E1%83%AC%E1%83%95%E1%83%90%E1%83%93%E1%83%98&oq=%E1%83%9B%E1%83%AC%E1%83%95%E1%83%90%E1%83%93%E1%83%98&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l7.983j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8"
    ),
    Entry(
        "მაკარონის წასახემსებელი",
        "https://gemrielia.ge/recipe/6594-xraSuna-makaronis-wasaxemsebeli-romelic-wuTebSi-mzaddeba/"
    )
)
```